# How to create a Matrix Relation field / relate Matrix Blocks to other Elements

Tags: plugin-development, field

I would like to create a field / a way to relate a certain Matrix Block to another Element. Is this possible?

For example:

Entry A contains a Matrix Field `matrix` and has several blocks. I want to relate one of those blocks to Entry B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BaseRelationField` is able to relate all elements - even Matrix Blocks but it's a little bit tricky because in order to display everything properly you need to define `sources` but Matrix Blocks have no sources.

At first we need to make sure our Matrix Blocks have a valid source, otherwise this Javascript check messes all up

```
var $sources = this._getSourcesInList(this.getSourceContainer());

// No source, no party.
if ($sources.length === 0) {
    return false;
}
```

And nothing works So we need the following

```
Event::on(
    MatrixBlock::class,
    MatrixBlock::EVENT_REGISTER_SOURCES,
    function(RegisterElementSourcesEvent $event) {
        if (empty($event->sources)) {
            $event->sources[] = [
                'key'         => 'MySource',
                'label'       => 'All Matrixes',
                'defaultSort' => 'elements.id',
                'data'        => [
                    'handle' => 'matrix'
                ],
                'criteria'    => [
                    'typeId' => 21,
                    'fieldId' => 70 // <-- this is the matrix field of Entry A otherwise the values won't be populated
                ]
            ];
        }
    }
);
```

In order to display an identifier we need to set the `title` attribute to the block, otherwise all we see is an id.

```
Event::on(
    MatrixBlockQuery::class,
    MatrixBlockQuery::EVENT_AFTER_POPULATE_ELEMENT,
    function(PopulateElementEvent $event){
        $element = $event->element;
        if($element->getType()->handle === 'person'){ //<-- make it is the correct matrix block
            try{
                $element->title = $element->getFieldValue('firstName') . ' ' . $element->getFieldValue('lastName');
            }catch(Exception $exception){
                // whatever you need
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Since Matrix Blocks usually have no table attributes we need to define them as well

```
Event::on(
    MatrixBlock::class,
    MatrixBlock::EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES,
    function($event) {
        $event->tableAttributes['id'] = ['label' => 'ID'];
        $event->tableAttributes['email'] = ['label' => 'Email'];
    }
);
```

After that you can use the normal `BaseRelationField` and extend it like you are used to for custom element types